# gRPC server in Python with Unix domain socket

Tags: python, sockets, grpc

Will gRPC support in Python allow me to implement a server that listens on a Unix domain socket (as opposed to a port)? I am using Python 3.5.3 and `grpcio`/`grpcio-tools` 1.18.0.

So far, I have not been able to find any relevant example nor direct evidence. The [official](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html) [examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/v1.18.0/examples/python) use `server.add_insecure_port('[::]:50051')`, and its not clear how a socket could fit there.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently [`add_insecure_port(address)`](https://grpc.io/grpc/python/grpc.html) accepts Unix domain sockets in the format `unix:///var/run/test.sock` after all.

More details: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/naming.md

Comment: To be clear, this would require three slashes. As an example: `channel = grpc.insecure_channel('unix:///tmp/foo/test.sock')`

Comment: More details on gRPC name resolution can be found [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/naming.md).