# how exactly does gRPC for python handles unix domain sockets

Tags: python, sockets, grpc, unix-socket, grpc-python

After trying a few things, I got to a point where I can run client-server gRPC connection that is UDS based on the same host. Since I didn't find any detailed documentation for this setup, my main concern is that I don't know if I use gRPC API properly.
Any reference/resource/explanation would be warmly welcomed

sources I looked at:
[gRPC python API](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/)
[gRPC python docs](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/)
[gRPC server in Python with Unix domain socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54844882/grpc-server-in-python-with-unix-domain-socket) (SO)

gRPC connection:

###### server

```py
import grpc
import my_pb2_grpc
from concurrent import futures

server = None
#...
class Listener(my_pb2_grpc.MyServiceServicer):
  #...

def create_connection():
    if server is None:
        server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1))
        my_pb2_grpc.add_MyServiceServicer_to_server(Listener(), server)
        server.add_insecure_port("unix:///path/to/uds.sock")
        server.start()

def stop_connection():
    if server:
        server.stop(0)
        server = None
```

###### client

```py
import grpc
import my_pb2_grpc

channel = None
stub = None
#...

def create_connection():
    if channel is None:
        channel = grpc.insecure_channel("unix:///path/to/uds.sock")
        stub = my_pb2_grpc.MyServiceStub(channel)

def stop_connection():
    if channel:
        channel.close()
        channel = None
        stub = None
```

Comment: About UDS support, gRPC Python is a wrapper library over gRPC Core, which does have official UDS support, see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/lib/iomgr/unix_sockets_posix.h. The way you are using the API is correct.

Comment: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/uds/greeter_server.py